# How to find $x$ on the eigen vector subspace causing $x^TAx=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$ is a symmetric sign indefinite matrix and none of its eigen values is zero. If $x$ is moving from positive to negative eigen vector, at some $x$,  $x^TAx=0$ will occur. Therefore, there exists atleast one $x$ vector on the subspace created by the two eigen vectors (positive and negative), which gives  $x^TAx=0$. How can I find that $x$.

Comment: do you just need to find it numerically?

Comment: I'm looking for an analytical solution

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_1,x_2$ be eigenvectors associated with $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$.  Note that for $t \in [0,1]$, if we set
$x = (1-t) x_1 + tx_2$, we find that (since $x_1^Tx_2 = 0$)
$$
x^TAx = \lambda_1(1-t)^2 + \lambda_2 t^2 = (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t^2 - 2\lambda_1 t + \lambda_1
$$
if we set $x^TAx$ equal to zero and solve for $t$, we find
$$
t = \frac{\lambda_1 \pm \sqrt{- \lambda_1\lambda_2}}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}
$$

---

Yet another method: set $x = \cos\theta x_1 + \sin \theta x_2$ for $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$ and find
$$
x^TAx = \lambda_1 \cos^2 \theta + \lambda_2 \sin^2 \theta
$$
setting $x^TAx = 0$ yields
$$
\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta} = -\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2} \implies 
\theta = \arctan\left(\sqrt{-\lambda_1/\lambda_2}\right) \implies\\
\cos \theta = \frac{1}{1 - \lambda_1/\lambda_2}, \qquad
\sin \theta = \frac{\sqrt{-\lambda_1/\lambda_2}}{1 - \lambda_1/\lambda_2}
$$
notably: if $x_1,x_2$ are unit vectors, then so is the resulting $x$.

Comment: Nice! Might be worth to precise that the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are of distinct signs so that the $x_1,x_2$ are indeed orthogonal and $\sqrt{-\lambda_1\lambda_2}\in\Bbb R$